# Checking if a select statement returns something with an IF

Tags: mysql

I am selecting a value from a table and i want to do something if the select statement returns something or fails to return something.

This is the code

```
IF NOT NULL(select member_club_id from members where member_name=the_temp_name AND membership_year=the_temp_membership_year where member_id=lesmember)

THEN

update the_temp SET the_temp_status='fail' where the_temp_name=member_name;

else
/* More Code...*/
```

The code produces produces a syntax error.In my code above,the plan is if the select statement returns something,then run the code below which is an update.

How am i supposed the if to test whether the select actually selects something or not?.

Comment: you want `if exists(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IF EXISTS(select ...)` etc ....